# Как сгенерить словарь на основе двух словарей с разным количеством параметров

Tags: python, циклы, словари

Имеется два словаря с данными:

1. `REVERSE_URLS = {'INDEX_URL': "reverse('posts:home_page')",'GROUP_URL': "reverse('posts:group_list', args=[GROUP_SLUG])", 'PROFILE_URL': "reverse('posts:profile', args=[USERNAME])"}`
2. `dict_values = {'page_1': 10, 'page_2': 3}`

Мне нужно сформировать новый словарь, где ключами будут ключи из `REVERSE_URLS`, а значениями будут парметры словаря `dict_values`. При этом если в словаре `dict_values` будет больше чем 1 параметр (например их 2), то в формат ключа в получаемом словаре должен динамически изменять в зависимости от этого и быть таким: `INDEX_URL_page1: 1`.

В итоге ожидается вот такой словарь:

```
{'INDEX_URL_page1': 10, 'INDEX_URL_page2': 3, 'GROUP_URL_page1': 10, 
 'GROUP_URL_page2': 3, 'PROFILE_URL_page1': 10, 'PROFILE_URL_page2': 3}
```

Я пробую следующую конструкцию:

```
REVERSE_URLS = {
    'INDEX_URL': "reverse('posts:home_page')",
    'GROUP_URL': "reverse('posts:group_list', args=[GROUP_SLUG])",
    'PROFILE_URL': "reverse('posts:profile', args=[USERNAME])",
}
dict_values = {'page_1': 10, 'page_2': 3}
urls = {
    f'{reverse_url}_page{i}: {values}'
    for reverse_url in REVERSE_URLS.keys()
        for values in dict_values.values()
            for i in range(1, len(dict_values) + 1)}
```

В итоге получается совсем не то что нужно:

```
{'INDEX_URL_page2: 10', 'GROUP_URL_page2: 3', 'PROFILE_URL_page1: 10',
 'PROFILE_URL_page2: 10', 'INDEX_URL_page2: 3', 'PROFILE_URL_page2: 3', 
 'INDEX_URL_page1: 3', 'PROFILE_URL_page1: 3', 'GROUP_URL_page1: 3', 
 'INDEX_URL_page1: 10', 'GROUP_URL_page2: 10', 'GROUP_URL_page1: 10'}
```

**Как это сделать?**

Comment: Как минимум `f'{reverse_url}_page{i}: {values}'` -> `f'{reverse_url}_page{i}': values`, чтобы получился словарь, а не множество

Comment: Да, это отчасти помогло, но вывод все же не тот. Значения не изменяются. Везде стоит '3'

Comment: `urls = {
    f'{reverse_url}_page{i}': values
    for reverse_url in REVERSE_URLS.keys()
    for i, values in enumerate(dict_values.values(), 1)
}
`

Comment: Danis, спасибо, твое решение работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Чтобы получался словарь вместо множества, нужно заменить `f'{reverse_url}_page{i}: {values}'` на `f'{reverse_url}_page{i}': values`
2. Внутренние два цикла у вас дают все сочетания значений индекса `i` и значений из словаря `dict_values` (2x2 = 4 пары). Вместо этого нужен один цикл, который будет получать значения и соответствующие им номера страницы (всего две пары).

Для простоты для сначала делаем, что в `dict_values` ключи - сразу номера страниц:

```
REVERSE_URLS = {
    'INDEX_URL': "reverse('posts:home_page')",
    'GROUP_URL': "reverse('posts:group_list', args=[GROUP_SLUG])",
    'PROFILE_URL': "reverse('posts:profile', args=[USERNAME])",
}

dict_values = {1: 10, 2: 3}
urls = {
    f'{reverse_url}_page{page_index}': page_value
    for reverse_url in REVERSE_URLS.keys()
        for page_index, page_value in dict_values.items()}

print(urls)
```

Вывод:

```
{'INDEX_URL_page1': 10, 'INDEX_URL_page2': 3, 'GROUP_URL_page1': 10,
 'GROUP_URL_page2': 3, 'PROFILE_URL_page1': 10, 'PROFILE_URL_page2': 3}
```

Далее, для получения номеров из строк вида `page_1`, `page_2` можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
import re

...

dict_values = {'page_1': 10, 'page_2': 3}


def page_to_index(page: str) -> int:
    return int(re.search(r"page_(\d+)", page).group(1))


urls = {
    f'{reverse_url}_page{page_to_index(page)}': page_value
    for reverse_url in REVERSE_URLS.keys()
        for page, page_value in dict_values.items()}

...
```

Или модуль [`parse`](https://pypi.org/project/parse/):

```
from parse import parse


def page_to_index(page: str) -> int:
    return parse("page_{:d}", page)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

вот такой код потестируйте, с вашим примером работает:

```
d = {}
for k,v in dict_values.items():
    keys = [f'{i}_{k}' for i in REVERSE_URLS]
    d.update(dict.fromkeys(keys,v))

>>> d
'''
{'INDEX_URL_page_1': 10,
 'GROUP_URL_page_1': 10,
 'PROFILE_URL_page_1': 10,
 'INDEX_URL_page_2': 3,
 'GROUP_URL_page_2': 3,
 'PROFILE_URL_page_2': 3}
```